# How do I access values in the data structure returned by XML::Simple?

Tags: perl, data-structures, reference

Hi everyone,
This is very simple for perl programmers but not beginners like me,
I have one xml file and I processed using XML::Simple like this

```
my $file="service.xml";
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
 my $data = $xml->XMLin("$file", ForceArray =>  ['Service','SystemReaction',  
                                      'Customers', 'Suppliers','SW','HW'],);
```

Dumping out `$data`, it looks like this:

```
$data = {
   'Service' => [{
         'Suppliers' => [{
               'SW' => [
                  {'Path' => '/work/service.xml',  'Service' => 'b7a'},
                  {'Path' => '/work/service1.xml', 'Service' => 'b7b'},
                  {'Path' => '/work/service2.xml', 'Service' => 'b5'}]}
         ],
         'Id' => 'SKRM',
         'Customers' =>
            [{'SW' => [{'Path' => '/work/service.xml', 'Service' => 'ASOC'}]}],
         'Des'  => 'Control the current through the pipe',
         'Name' => ' Control unit'
      },
      {
         'Suppliers' => [{
               'HW' => [{
                     'Type'    => 'W',
                     'Path'    => '/work/hardware.xml',
                     'Nr'      => '18',
                     'Service' => '1'
                  },
                  {
                     'Type'    => 'B',
                     'Path'    => '/work/hardware.xml',
                     'Nr'      => '7',
                     'Service' => '1'
                  },
                  {
                     'Type'    => 'k',
                     'Path'    => '/work/hardware.xml',
                     'Nr'      => '1',
                     'Service' => '1'
                  }]}
         ],
         'Id' => 'ADTM',
         'Customers' =>
            [{'SW' => [{'Path' => '/work/service.xml', 'Service' => 'SDCR'}]}],
         'Des'  => 'It delivers actual motor speed',
         'Name' => ' Motor Drivers and Diognostics'
      },
      # etc.
   ],
   'Systemreaction' => [
      # etc.
   ],
};
```

How to access each elements in the service and systemReaction(not provided). because I am using "$data" in further processing. So I need to access each Id,customers, suppliers values in each service. How to get particular value from service to do some process with that value.for example I need to get all Id values form service and create nodes for each id values.

To get Type and Nr value I tried like this

```
 foreach my $service (@{ $data->{Service}[1]{Suppliers}[0]{HW}[0] }) {
 say $service->{Nr};
 }
 foreach my $service (@{ $data->{Service}[1]{Suppliers}[0]{HW}[0] }) {
 say $service->{Type};

  }
```

can you help me how to get all Nr and Type values from Supplier->HW.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest reading perldocs [Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [References and Nested Data Structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). They contain an introduction and full explanation of how to access data like that.

But, for example, you can access the service ID by doing:

```
say $data->{Service}[0]{Id}   # prints SKRM
```

You could go through all the services, printing their ID, with a loop:

```
foreach my $service (@{ $data->{Service} }) {
    say $service->{Id};
}
```

### In response to your edit

`$data->{Service}[1]{Suppliers}[0]{HW}[0]` is an hash reference (you can check this quickly by either using [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper) or [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dump) on it, or just the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function). In particular, it is `{ Nr => 18, Path => "/work/hardware.xml", Service => 1, Type => "W" }`

In other words, you've almost got it—you just went one level too deep. It should be:

```
foreach my $service (@{ $data->{Service}[1]{Suppliers}[0]{HW} }) {
 say $service->{Nr};
}
```

Note the lack of the final `[0]` that you had.

Comment: Sorry for asking I gone through reference tutorial but still i am confusing getting "type" and "Nr" because its nested elements. these arrays and hashes makes me difficult. can you some suggestion how to get that elements.

Comment: @verendra: In that dump, each `{` is introducing a new hashref, each `[` a new arrayref. So one `Nr` would be `$data->{Service}[1]{Suppliers}[0]{HW}[0]{Nr}` ... also, you may find other XML modules easier to use; have you looked at `XML::DOM` for example?

Comment: @verendra: Also, if you're having trouble understanding perlreftut or perlref, I'm sure SO would welcome specific questions about whichever parts are confusing/unclear/incomprehensible.

Comment: I have small doubt again can you have a look at my edited post. I tried something like but its not working why?